# How to access iframe inside and iframe using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the below code that is in my DOM and I want to get height of the #iframe2

Basically, I have to change the height of #iframe1 whenever the height of #iframe2 changes. I have added a link to screenshot below for what I am exactly trying to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCXvC.png

```
<div id="gpt-leaderboard">
   <iframe id="iframe1">
         <iframe id="iframe2" >
           <!-- Banner with dynamic height loads here-->
         </iframe>
    </iframe>
 </div>
```

I am using the below code to get the height but it is not working

```
document.getElementById("gpt-leaderboard").getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].style.height;
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: `style="height: 90px;"`

Comment: What are you trying to do nesting iframes with no source!?

Comment: iframes have their own document so you will have to retrieve that in order to look inside them.  iframe2 is nested inside the iframe1 document, not inside the iframe1 tag.

Comment: I think you have an extra `getElementsByTagName()` method in there.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do will not work assuming your implementation is that your two iframes are nested in the main page.

when `iframe1` is loaded, it will be defaulted to a blank document. This will mean `iframe2` is removed, as anything inside the `<iframe>` tag will be replaced.

To just get your HTML correct, you will have to have your first `iframe`'s `src` attribute set to a page containing `iframe2`

Edit: You can see an example of one approach using jquery here: http://jsfiddle.net/D9BX8/ (note: i have used jquery instead of "raw JS" since it's what i know. I'm sure with some googling you can translate it down to basic JS if you don't use jquery on your site)

Comment: Things is I cannot use jQuery. I have to write it in pure JS. Using jQuery would have made it much simpler :(

Comment: jQuery is just a library. It still boils down to standard JS. You just need to work out how. A i said, it was just an example showing that it's possible to do, once you ensure your HTML is correct and present.